# Flutter: How to add a zoom functionality to image

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app, a custom image is built with the following code

customImage.dart

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget cachedNetworkImage(mediaUrl) {
  return CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: mediaUrl,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    placeholder: (context, url)=>
    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error) ,
  );
}
```

I want to add a functionality to pinch to zoom on this image,how can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Sorry I haven't tried anything, actually I am learning flutter, just wanted to know is there any method available to zoom a photo in flutter.

Comment: I will try to post my tries and approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use Flutter's bulid-in `InteractiveViewer` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html 
A widget that enables pan and zoom interactions with its child.

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

Widget cachedNetworkImage(mediaUrl) {
  return CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: mediaUrl,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    placeholder: (context, url) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
  );
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        minScale: 0.1,
        maxScale: 1.6,
        child: cachedNetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/250?image=9"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `photo_view` for this. It allows you to create zoomable image widgets without dealing with pinch gesture or sth.

```
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view.dart';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: PhotoView(
      imageProvider: AssetImage("assets/image.jpg"),
    )
  );
}
```

Source: https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view